# Woocommerce newProduct() Taxonomy is Not Working

Tags: php, attributes, woocommerce, product, taxonomy

Can you show me what I'm doing wrong?

My code to add a new product to Woocommerce looks like this right now:

```
function newProduct( $idERP, $titulo, $conteudo, $preco, $precoDesconto, $sku, $peso, $comprimento, $largura, $altura, $estoque, $variacoes, $categorias ){

        global $woocommerce;

        $titulo = utf8_encode($titulo);
        $conteudo = utf8_encode($conteudo);

        $my_post = array(
          'post_title'    => $titulo,
          'post_content'  => $conteudo,
          'post_status'   => 'pending',
          'post_author'   => 6,
          'post_type'     =>'product'
        );
        $product_ID = wp_insert_post( $my_post );

        if ( $product_ID ){

          if( $preco == $precoDesconto){
              add_post_meta($product_ID, '_price',         $precoDesconto );
          }else{
              add_post_meta($product_ID, '_regular_price', $preco );
              add_post_meta($product_ID, '_price',         $precoDesconto );
              add_post_meta($product_ID, '_sale_price',    $precoDesconto );
          }


          add_post_meta($product_ID, '_sku',           $sku );
          add_post_meta($product_ID, '_weight',        $peso );
          add_post_meta($product_ID, '_length',        $comprimento );
          add_post_meta($product_ID, '_width',         $largura );
          add_post_meta($product_ID, '_height',        $altura );
          add_post_meta($product_ID, '_stock',         $this->estoque($estoque) );
          add_post_meta($product_ID, '_idERP',         $idERP ); //ID from erp
          wp_set_object_terms( $product_ID,  'variable', 'product_type' );
          //wp_set_object_terms( $product_ID, $categorias, 'product_cat');

          $guardaVariacoes = array();$i = 1;
          foreach($variacoes as $v){
            $vid = wp_insert_post(
                array(
                  'post_title'    => 'Variacao #' . $i,
                  'post_name'     => 'product-' . $product_ID . '-variation-' . $i,
                  'post_status'   => 'publish',
                  'post_parent'   => $product_ID,
                  'post_type'     => 'product_variation',
                  'guid'          =>  home_url() . '/?product_variation=product-' . $product_ID . '-variation-' . $i
                )
            );

            if( $v[1] == $v[2] ){
                update_post_meta( $vid, '_regular_price', $v[1]);
            }else{
                update_post_meta( $vid, '_price', $v[2] );
                update_post_meta( $vid, '_regular_price', $v[1]);
                update_post_meta( $vid, '_sale_price',  $v[2] );
            }

            update_post_meta( $vid, '_stock', $this->estoque($v[0]) );
            update_post_meta( $vid, '_weight', $v[3]);
            update_post_meta( $vid, '_width', $v[4]);
            update_post_meta( $vid, '_height', $v[5]);
            update_post_meta( $vid, '_length', $v[6]);
            update_post_meta( $vid, '_sku', $v[8]);
            update_post_meta( $vid, '_idERP', $v[9]);

            foreach($v[7] as $nAtr=>$vAtr){
                $nomeAtributo = strtolower(trim($nAtr));


                 $tt = $nomeAtributo;
                 if(strtolower($tt) == 'tamanho')$tt = 'pa_tamanho';
                 if(strtolower($tt) == 'cor')$tt = 'pa_cor';


                update_post_meta( $vid, 'attribute_'.$tt, trim($vAtr));
                $temp = $tt.'|'.$nAtr;
                if( !array_key_exists($temp,$guardaVariacoes) ) $guardaVariacoes[$temp] = array();
                $guardaVariacoes[$temp][] = $vAtr;  
            }
            $i++;
          }

          $product_attributes = array();
          foreach($guardaVariacoes as $r=>$s){

              $r = explode('|',$r);

              $temp = array();
              foreach($s as $w){

                  $w = trim($w);

                  if( strtoupper($w) == 'UNICA'  ){
                      $w = 'Única';
                  }
                  if( strtoupper($w) == 'UNICO'  ){
                      $w = 'Único';
                  }


                  if( array_search( $w,$temp)===false){
                     if( strtoupper(trim($r[1])) == 'COR'){
                         $temp[] = ucfirst(strtolower($w)); 
                      }else{
                          $temp[] = $w; 
                    } 
                  }
              }
              $s = array_unique($temp);



             $tt = $r[1];
             if(strtolower($tt) == 'tamanho')$tt = 'pa_tamanho';
             if(strtolower($tt) == 'cor')$tt = 'pa_cor';


              $product_attributes[$r[0]] = array(
                'name' => $tt, 
                'value' => implode(' | ', $s ),
                'position' => 1,
                'is_visible' => 1,
                'is_variation' => 1,
                'is_taxonomy' => 1  //MY PROBLEM IS HERE
              );
          }
          update_post_meta($product_ID, '_product_attributes', $product_attributes);
        }
        return $product_ID;
    }
```

When I change the code like so...

```
    'is_taxonomy' => 1
```

...it works, but it doesn't work for "search layered filters", which means I have to use taxonomy.

How do I do that without losing the "attributes" inside my product?

Comment: Just a FYI:  You should be using `sanitize_title_with_dashes` for the title.  What are `search layered filters`?  Are you referring to the categories that get set in `wp_terms` table?

Comment: Hello Solomon!  The layer filter I mean, is that Widget we put in sidebar. So when someone search for "tshirt". it shows the color or the size and you can filter the search. I dont know the real name of this, its my first days with Woocommerce.  Looks like this search use the taxonomy, and when I set to 1, I dont see the product attributes when editing it. So Im making something wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds to me like you are trying to set Categories for products, and correct me if I'm wrong please.  If this is the case, you don't want to use taxonomies.  First, you are missing a ton of meta_keys for the product and all of it's variations.  I suggest you install a fresh copy of WooCommerce plugin on a Fresh copy of Wordpress.  Create a product manually in the back-end with 2 variations, and take a look at the `wp_posts` and `wp_postmeta` (`post_id`, `meta_key`, and `meta_values`).  For variations, there are more values for the actual product id in the `wp_postmeta` table than that of the variations.  `_max_variation_sale_price_id`, `_max_variation_sale_price`, `_min_variation_sale_price_id`, `_min_variation_sale_price`, etc. etc. etc.  There is also another serialized array, `_default_attributes`, that you can just make an empty array and serialize it, for the product so that it has it's defaults set.

So, if you are referring to Categories and want to assign products to categories so that you can click on a category and see that product in there... than do the following:

Keep `is_taxonomy` set to 0
`is_visible` doesn't matter, if you want to see it under Additional Info, than set to 1, otherwise, it should still show all different variations, but I suppose it depends on your theme's way of handling this.
`position` needs to start at 1 and be incremented each time, so use a variable for this, example:

```
$position = 1;
foreach($guardaVariacoes as $r=>$s) {

    // your top code... down to where the _product_attributes array begins...

    $product_attributes[$r[0]] = array(
        'name' => $tt, 
        'value' => implode(' | ', $s),
        'position' => $position,
        'is_visible' => count($s) > 1 ? 0 : 1,
        'is_variation' => count($s) > 1 ? 1 : 0,
        'is_taxonomy' => 0
    );

    $position++;
}
```

To create and assign categories on the fly for products you use: [`term_exists`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/term_exists) (will return 0 or NULL if term doesn't exist, you can check with `empty()`), [`wp_insert_term`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_term) (if the term doesn't exist), insert it so that you can assign the category to the product.  Example below if you want to insert a sub-brand category into a parent brand category, just an example of how I add categories to products (`wp_term_relationships` table assigns the categories to each product, via the products/posts ID value):

```
// Check if Brand exists or not...
$brand = term_exists('brand', 'product_cat', 0);
$category = 'new category';
$cat_name = addslashes(ucwords(strtolower($category)));
$cats['brand'] = array(
    'name' => $cat_name,
    'slug' => sanitize_title_with_dashes($category)
);

if (!empty($brand))
{
    $subbrand = term_exists($cats['brand']['slug'], 'product_cat', $brand['term_id']);

    if (empty($subbrand))
    {
        $subbrand = wp_insert_term(
            $cats['brand']['name'],
            'product_cat',
            array(
                'slug' => $cats['brand']['slug'],
                'parent'=> $brand['term_id']
            )
        );
    }
} else {

    $brand = wp_insert_term(
        'Brand',
        'product_cat',
        array(
            'slug' => 'brand',
            'parent'=> 0 // This means it will be at the first level!
        )
    );

    $subbrand = term_exists($cats['brand']['slug'], 'product_cat', $brand['term_id']);

    if (empty($subbrand))
    {
        $subbrand = wp_insert_term(
            $cats['brand']['name'],
            'product_cat',
            array(
                'slug' => $cats['brand']['slug'],
                'parent'=> $brand['term_id']
            )
        );
    }
}

$categories = array(
    'product_id' => // put the product id value in here!
    'terms' => array()
);

if (!empty($subbrand))
{
    $categories['terms']['subbrands'] = $subbrand;
}

// Now insert into term_relationships table for that product and that's all folks...
foreach($categories['terms'] as $type => $nfo)
{
    $wpdb->insert(
        $wpdb->prefix . "term_relationships", 
        array(
            'object_id' => $categories['product_id'], 
            'term_taxonomy_id' => intval($nfo['term_taxonomy_id']),
            'term_order' => 0
        ),
        array('%d', '%d', '%d')
    );
}
```

So, hopefully this helps you to build categories for your products, while still keeping your product attributes in tact in the search filter.  Good Luck.